# How do I set a proxy in Monodevelop to get to the Add-in Manager repos?

Tags: windows, proxy, monodevelop

I have monodevelop running great except for the fact that I need to get the "Subsversion Add-in for Windows" and my work proxy is blocking the repo.  Any idea of how I can specify the proxy info so I can get to the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, it uses the normal .NET proxy settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: mhutch, perhaps I am just too inexperienced with MonoDevelop at this point, but I'm not sure which config file to put that in.  MonoDevelop.exe.config ?  Again, the issue is with the Add-In manager in the IDE being blocked by the proxy and not knowing how to skirt around it.

Comment: If you put it in your machine.config it will be picked up by all .NET apps on the system. The default setting in machine.config is to load the settings from Internet Explorer. However, yes, you could indeed put it in the MD binary's config (mdrun.exe.config) if you just want to override it for MD.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Coincidentally, although I work full-time on MD now, I also implemented the (simplistic) proxy autodetection in Mono on Linux a few years ago when I was behind a proxy at University, which is why I'm familiar with it :)

Comment: I wish there was something on OSX Lion like that (that actually worked, rather than the network proxy settings.)

Comment: Mono has a machine.config too, though beware it will be replaced whenever you update Mono: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/etc/mono/4.0/machine.config

Comment: And Mac proxy autodetection has now been implemented in Mono, though it hasn't yet been released.